# Cannot connect to MYSQL Server using workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I have just installed MYSQL8.0 workbench and have come up against an issue when trying to establish a connection.  When try to setup my first connection,  i get the following message when trying to test connection

Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root.
Access Denied for user'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

There is a lot of material on here about resolving this issue but a lot of if involves code in either cmd or Ubuntu.  When i try the proposed solutions through cmd I get errors saying this is not a recognized command (ie i tried this line mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 in cmd but it does not work; i get a message saying is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

My question is, am i able to solve this problem within workbench iteself?  If not, what terminal should I be using in order to access SQL and run the code suggested above.

Comment: Did you also install MySQL?  If you only installed the workbench you might not have the database running.

Comment: yes MySQL server is installed and running (I checked services to make sure it was running).

Comment: you can resolve the issue in workbench by providing the correct username and password. This is not really a programming issue.

Comment: your solution isn't helpful as again their is code in the solution that I don't know where to input.  when i input the command into cmd i get a message saying the command is not recognizable.